# テーブルのカラムには存在しない独自に追加したプロパティも to_json で出力したい

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, json, rails-activerecord

下記のようなテーブルがあるとします。

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMEN
  name VARCHAR(32),
  created_datetime TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

このテーブルのカラムとは別に`hoge`という名前でUserモデルにプロパティを追加し、ActiveRecordで操作できるようにしたいと考えています。

具体的には下記のように、追加したプロパティに値をセットしjson文字列化したいです。

```
users = User.all
users.each do |u|
  u.hoge = true
end

return users.to_json
```

---

`attr_accessor`を使うことで実現できるかと思い試してみましたが、値のセットはできるようになるものの、to_jsonで取得される文字列に追加したプロパティは含まれていませんでした。

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :hoge
end
```

---

何らかの方法でテーブルにないカラムをモデルに追加することは可能でしょうか？

Comment: jsonのタグを追加しました。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

データベースと ひもづいていない attribute をもつ方法として、virtual attribute というものがあります。
json の構造変更や項目を追加するなら、as_jsoon を再定義する方法があります。

参考情報：
- [railsのvirtual attributeのお話](http://stpanisush.hatenablog.com/entry/2013/07/25/114838)
- [RailsでVirtual Attributes(仮想的な属性)をする](http://ruby-rails.hatenadiary.com/entry/20141229/1419856433)
- [RAILSCAST – 016-VIRTUAL-ATTRIBUTES](http://patrickperey.com/railscast-016-virtual-attributes/)
- [Add Virtual attribute to active record object to output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26076173/add-virtual-attribute-to-active-record-object-to-output)
- [Rails JSON Virtual Attributes](https://jesse.sh/rails-virtual-attributes/)
- [Build your own JSON presenters with POROs (Plain Old Ruby Object)](http://samurails.com/gems/poro-json-presenters/)

Comment: ありがとうございます。
as_jsonを再定義することで実現できました。

Answer (score 2):

```
return users.to_json
```

`to_json` を呼ぶとき、`:methods` 引数を使って

```
return users.to_json(methods: :hoge)
```

とすると `"hoge"` が含まれたJSONが返ります。

Comment: ありがとうございます。こちらの方法でも実現できました。